# NSOutline View Drag-n-Drop Problem

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drag-and-drop, nstableview, nsoutlineview

Dear All, 
I am fighting with NSOutline View to perform drag-n-drop within the table since last 2-3 day but couldn't get what i am doing wrong, 
This is what i have done so far,

Requirement, 
1 -- I want to have a transparent or with some background image NSoutlineview in my view, to do that, i need to overwrite drawRect method of NSOutlineView, this is what i have done

in header file

```
@interface MyCustomOutlineView:NSOutlineView{
NSImage *pBackgroundImage;

}

- setBackgroundImage:(NSImage *)pImage;
```

In source file, i just overwrite drawRect and some other stuffs to draw the background image or to make it transparent and this is working fine,

Now in my view, i have declared the NSOutlineView object like that,

/*
* My Custom view will have capability to draw the gradient and other effects
*/

```
@interface OutlineParentView:MyCustomView<NSOutlineDataSource>{
   MyCustomOutlineView *pOutlineView;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain)MyCustomOutlineView *pOutlineView;
```

In source file, implemented following method , 
This method will be called from the initWIthFrame

```
#define OutlineViewPrivateDataType "MyOutlinePrivateData"
-(void)InitOutlineView{
    NSRect          scrollFrame = [self bounds];
    NSScrollView*   scrollView  = [[[NSScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:scrollFrame] autorelease];
    [scrollView setBorderType:NSNoBorder];
    [scrollView setHasVerticalScroller:YES];
    [scrollView setHasHorizontalScroller:NO];
    [scrollView setAutohidesScrollers:YES];
    [scrollView setDrawsBackground: NO];
    NSRect          clipViewBounds  = [[scrollView contentView] bounds];
    pOutlineView       = [[[CommUICustomOutlineView alloc] initWithFrame:clipViewBounds] autorelease];
    NSTableColumn*  firstColumn     = [[[NSTableColumn alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"firstColumn"] autorelease];
    ImageTextCell *pCell = [[ImageTextCell alloc]init];
    [firstColumn setDataCell:pCell];
    [pCell setDataDelegate:self];
    [firstColumn setWidth:25];
    [pOutlineView  addTableColumn:firstColumn];
    [pOutlineView setRowHeight:30];
    [pOutlineView setDataSource:self];

    /* setData delegate implemented in the MyOutlineView to handle some of event in this  
       interface if i don't write this, then i can't handle the menu event on the 
       Outlineview  
     */
    [pOutlineView setDataDelegate:self];

    **/* On this line i am getting one warning, saying OutlineParentView doesn't implement    
       NSOutlineView delegate protocol */**
    [pOutlineView setDelegate:self];
    [scrollView setDocumentView:pOutlineView];
    /* I don't want group row to be highlighted */
    [pOutlineView setSelectionHighlightStyle:NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleSourceList];
    [pOutlineView registerForDraggedTypes:
         [NSArray arrayWithObjects:OutlineViewPrivateDataType,nil]];

    [pOutlineView setDraggingSourceOperationMask:NSDragOperationEvery forLocal:YES];
    [scrollView setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable|NSViewHeightSizable];
        [self addSubview:scrollView];
    [self setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
    [self log:@"Outline view created "];

}
```

Other Important method related to Drag-n-Drop implemented as below

```
- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView writeItems:(NSArray *)items toPasteb oard:(NSPasteboard *)pboard{
    [self log:@"write Items"];
    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:items];
    [pboard declareTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:OutlineViewPrivateDataType] 
    owner:self];
    [pboard setData:data forType:OutlineViewPrivateDataType];
    return YES;
}

    - (NSDragOperation)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView validateDrop:(id < NSDraggingInfo >)info proposedItem:(id)item proposedChildIndex:(NSInteger)index
    {
        NSLog(@"validate Drop");
        return NSDragOperationEvery;
    }
    - (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView acceptDrop:(id < NSDraggingInfo >)info item:(id)item childIndex:(NSInteger)index{
        [self log:@"inside accept drop for NSView "];
        return YES;
    }
```

I checked apple DragnDrop Sample code, but couldn't get what i am doing wrong, 
i believe, some problem with the

[pOutlineView setDelegate:self]

Function, but how to solve that, that i don't know, 
I upgraded recently from MyTableView to MyOutlineView, recently i was able to perform Drag-nDrop on the Custom Table view, 
Remaining things are working fine, like DataSource etc...

Thanks in Advance 
Kind Regards
Rohan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was setting ColumnWidth so drag-n-drop working for the width which has been set, not on the full row my mistake :(

```
 [firstColumn setWidth:25];
```

Removing this line working fine

But guys facing some other problem 
[Regarding NSoutlineView and WriteItem | Drag-and-Drop Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897167/regarding-nsoutlineview-and-writeitem-dran-n-drop-problem)